# Query to break and get the value in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I want a query from a column which will break the output and give the result which I want.

For Ex: If the Output of the column is

> SAMARTH NAGAR¸LOKHANDWLA COMPLEX¸ANDHERI(W)

I want to only display `Andheri(w)`
and If the output is single word say `Andheri(W)`, it should not break it

I m using `sql-server 2005`

Here is some more details related to `tablename` and `columnname`

```
Select distinct Add2 from emp_mst
```

Comment: Are the values separated with a comma in column 'Add2'?

Comment: @HashPsi: Yes, the values are separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct 
  case 
    when charindex('¸', Add2) != 0 then
      reverse(substring(reverse(Add2), 0, charindex('¸', reverse(Add2))))
    else Add2
  end
from emp_mst
```

Comment: Yes will try tomorrow as I left for the office today. Thanks a lot for your reply though

Comment: I want this with `column name` with `Unique column` Ex: **ID**